# URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit,Account.Id,null,true) redirects to edit page but unable to save or cancel

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller, button-overrides, action

I'm using Account edit button override with custom visualforce page. In the visualforce page, it correctly redirects to that particular Account edit page, but the save and cancel button doesnt doesnot working click standard edit layout. Itstays in the same page and doesn't redircts back after saving/cancelling. Here is the page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" action="{!IF(
 (Account.RecordType.Name=='Engagement Plan'|| Account.RecordType.Name=='Strategic Initiative')
, URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit,Account.Id,null,true)
, '/apex/test_kk?id=Account.Id'
)}" >
<apex:variable value="{!Account.RecordType.Name}" var="recTypeName"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone help me what i'm missing here? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the appropriate URL params that tell the standard Save (*saveURL*) and Cancel (*retURL*) buttons where to go. These should go in your URLFOR function where the null currently is:

> URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit,Account.Id,['retURL'=***cancelDestination***, 'saveURL'=***saveDestination***],true)

Comment: thanks @RenegadeCoder, can you be more specific where i need to add this params?

Comment: Yes, I just doubled-checked the documentation and edited my answer

Comment: thanks @RenegadeCoder  a lot ! i'm updating my code accordingly

Comment: I might have goofed on the single quotes... I see some examples online that seem to show quotes around the param _values_ rather than the param _names_, so please let me know which is correct and I'll update my answer again

Comment: thanks again, but when setting retURL='/'+Account.Id it works fine , but its not working to return using a lookup field.  say if retURL='/'+Account.Product__c where Product__c is lookup to product, it errors out SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field:Account.Product__c. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Yes, that's a common issue with standard page controllers: it only queries into context the fields that are being used on the page. You can get around this by introducing another _apex:variable_ that references the field you need.  

You may also need to embed another nested URLFOR as the value for the _retURL_, because I've definitely run into an issue requiring that before (sorry, I don't remember the exact scenario that required it)

Comment: thanks a lot @RenegadeCoder .. i'll give it a try, curently the issue is resolved using an custom extension